# Namespacing imported libraries for clarity in Java

Tags: java, import

Is it possible to keep the namespace of the methods being imported in Java? I'm wondering from a technical and practical perspective.

For example, say I'm importing the [spark](http://sparkjava.com/) library so I can use it's `get()` method, I might do something like

```
import static spark.Spark.*;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    get(....);
    // do stuff
}
```

For someone looking at this (especially when the project is much bigger and several things are imported), it's not immediately obvious where "get()" comes from. I'd love to be able to do something like this

```
import static spark.*;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Spark.get(....);
    // do stuff
}
```

As you can see the `get()` call is now visually namespaced under `Spark`.

Is this generally seen as permissible, or are there drawbacks to this approach? If so, why is it that more projects don't use this approach?

Thanks!

Comment: I always add the class name on static calls.  I don't use static imports, because I think spelling it out is clearer.

Comment: I prefer the second. Are you asking if there is any way to force people to follow one form?

Comment: It's pretty subjective but in fact, most teams I've worked with prefer avoiding `*` imports, except in places where it definitely makes things cleaner and clearer. In tests, instead of saying `Assertions.assert(` this and `Mockito.mock(` that, hundreds of times, we do `assert(` and `mock(`. But in runtime code, we pretty much never use it. Imagine seeing a static factory method `of` in runtime code--you're definitely going to have to scroll up or click into that to know which `of` it is.

Comment: Google's internal practices say that you should only statically import a method where the unqualified name is clear from the context. For example, statically importing `newBuilder` is [strongly discouraged](http://errorprone.info/bugpattern/BadImport), because it comes on every proto class, so it is very unclear which `newBuilder` you are invoking. I would put `get()` firmly in the same category of "far too unclear"; I can't think of another *static* method that I'd get it confused with, but that fact notwithstanding, it's just not clear at all what it is "getting".

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, it all depends on what you are using really - class name on static calls is ok, but it becomes problematic when you are using something VERY often - because then you cover the logic behind a fake feeling meaning.

Also I'd say get is a pretty damn bad name for static method - if method names have more meaning, then they become less dependent on class name - but here we are left with no choice when using frameworks.

Comment: Thanks that makes sense to me. I was curious whether it was a frowned-upon practice but looks like it's not at all, and it's clearer for most (unless you're using it often)

Comment: @user2490003 I've seen both approaches in at work - and it seems that people don't really care if you do it this or that way - so long as you keep consistent within the scope.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the usage of static import in what you'd love to be able to do is incorrect. As is, it means import all static members of class `spark`, whereas `spark` is the package. Class `Spark` would be unknown and you get a compile error. Get rid of that `static` in the above, and you import all classes of spark package. You refer to the class members as `ClassName.member`, and the instance members as `instanceName.member`. Clash of class names themselves is rare. So, the scheme, as is, pretty readable and elegant.
But if your code uses a lot of static members of an imported class, referring them by prep-ending the class name each time could be cumbersome etc., so we have the short-cut way of static import. And the [Java documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/static-import.html) has a nice advice on this, which perhaps answers your question.

```
... So when should you use static import? Very sparingly! Only use it when you'd otherwise be tempted to declare local copies of constants, or to abuse inheritance (the Constant Interface Antipattern). In other words, use it when you require frequent access to static members from one or two classes
```

Comment: Thanks! Your first line clearly explains why `static` won't work here and why it should be removed. But as you go on to note, `import static.*` potentially imports way more than I need. Will it work to just `import static.Spark` and then I can use `Spark.get()` throughout my code as sort of a best-of-both-worlds approach?